# Why does "if constexpr" not compile with Visual Studio 2017 15.3?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

The `if constexpr` syntax introduced with C++17 should work with the `/std:c++14` compiler switch, according to this documentation: [C++17 Features In Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/).

However, it does not work. Instead, the following compiler error is generated:

> error C4984: 'if constexpr' is a C++17 language extension

Is the documentation wrong?

If so, how can `if constexpr` be compiled in Visual Studio 2017 15.3?

Comment: It says it supports it, it makes no claims that it's supported under `/std:c++14`; in fact it explicitly lists it as C++17 feature, so why do you expect it when you ask for an older standard?

Comment: It says: "[F] Supported under /std:c++14 with “warning C4984:..."
please see reference [F] below the table.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: Does the fact that it gave you an "error" for C4984 instead of a "warning" make you consider that maybe you compiled with warnings-as-errors?

Comment: @NicolBolas I tested the project with settings set by default, where "warnings-as-errors" is off (/WX-).

Comment: Ugh, they still don't support it by default, even though the warning level 4 recommends using it...

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the documentation linked in the question is inaccurate here.

To use `if constexpr` in Visual Studio 2017, you need to compile with either the `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++latest` switch.

Comment: I tried but using `if constexpr (std::is_same< T, stuff>::value) { thingthatbuilds; } else {thingthatdoesnt; }` fails with a... build error in the else part.

Comment: You can find this option via VS2017 UI: `Project Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Language` -> `C++ Language Standard` and pick `"ISO C++17 Standard"`. This option will be available if `Project Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `Platform Toolset` is set to `"Visual Studio 2017 (v141)"` or `"Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)"`